# Geofence is there any hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, latitude-longitude, cllocationmanager

is there any concept of hierarchy level for latitude and lognitude like,
india latitude and longitude is 21.0000,78.0000 respectively. and mumbai india latitude and longitude is 19.017614,72.856163 respectively. my question is when user enter in mumbai, and i am monitoring geofence for india. when user came to india, location manger

```
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
   {
       NSLog("you are in india");
   }
```

above mention delegate should get called. but it's not happening as of now.

Comment: have you assigned the CLLocationManagerDelegate to your class?

Comment: if i am monitoring for mumbai and my location change to mumbai this delegate method is getting called as expected. but i want it should called even my location changed to latitude and logitude of india.

Comment: Then Monitor for the respective lat. n Long. of india also, you can set the Geofencing accordingly

Comment: just take one scenario, i want when user came to india, my delegate should called. but user can come anywhere in india by flight. in that condition what to monitor ?